# Editing Python scripts on s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to open a Python script on the s3 bucket, make changes to it, save it and run it?

For example, if I SSH into a server on FileZilla, I can access the scripts on it, make changes to it, save and run it without having to download the script, making the changes and uploading every time I want to make changes.

Is there a way to do the same for scripts on the s3 bucket as well?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is **not possible** to do it directly on S3. S3 is only a object-based storage solution, not a file system.

You have to **download** it somewhere, **edit**, and then **upload** new version to S3. You can have some **third-party** tools that do this in the background.

One of such third-party tool is [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse):

> s3fs allows Linux and macOS to **mount an S3 bucket via FUSE**. s3fs preserves the native object format for files, allowing use of other tools like AWS CLI.

Among many other things, `s3fs-fuse` allows:

- allows random writes and appends